# Directory owned by a group that doesn't exist?

Tags: directory, group, gid

I'm witnessing a a directory which has for group owner "1002" ...
However I do not have any group with such ID (verified with `getent group | grep 1002` ).

Even `history | grep groupadd` gave nothing.

Where could that be coming from.
Any '100x' group ID is a user ID if I'm right no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Group IDs and User IDs are independent. The same number may be used for user "foo" and group "bar".

Some Linux distributions by default create a new group "foo" when you create user "foo", both having the same numerical ID. (This kills the very notion of group, IMHO.)

`ls` by default shows the group name, but the filesystem stores the numerical group ID. If a group is removed, files belonging to it are not, then `ls` shows the numerical ID.

So the situation you observe may come from, e.g.:

- creating a user who gets affected number 1002 and implying creation of group 1002, then removing this user (assuming the distribution tools then remove the associated group)
- syncing a file from another computer where its owning group has number 1002

Comment: Don't forget extracting files from an archive with `pax -p e` and the like.  There are questions on this site about that very thing.

Comment: amazing, I think that was it !! I created a user whom I then removed !
Thanks